# EditText - next button from keyboard - implementation

Tags: android

I have an EditText , after I write something and I click next i want to do a call to server.
for example if i have edittext a,
how I specify that the action has to happen just after I click next ?
I suppose that a.setOnClickLisner is not ok

Thank you in advance , 
Raluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
EditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
    {

        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) 
        {
                //Write your code here
}

    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                                    // PLACE CODE FOR CALLING SERVER.

                    return false;
                }
                return false;
                    }
});
```